# Stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document coded UI - C#

Tags: c#, reference, coded-ui-tests

I get the exception

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.76)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
```

I tried to understand what's going on. And what I saw was that the problem is probably when I changed the title of the browser after logging it seems that he can not access the browser although he find it (its url property has updated).

It seems that after he changed the title he isn't recognizing that it's the same process.

Direct access to the browser object is bringing null reference exception
Approach that does not directly - bringing fail above stale element

I have tried the following -

1. Adding `wait`
2. Browser `refresh`
3. `Browser.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);`
4. `Browser.locate.`

and nothing!

Could you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change the search configuration of the browser to do a wild card search (includes, not equals) on the browser title.